# Java, item shop discount math error

Tags: java, math, command-prompt, discount

This program is meant to act as a shop, with a number being inputted for a corresponding item and a quantity. The catch is that if you want three or more items you receive a 10% discount on the purchase and any decimals should be truncated (staying within whole numbers of the int data type). The program will run, however **the discount isn't calculated and is always stated as 0** though the program will run. Check it out!

```
int item, longsword, shortsword, warhammer, ring, potion, itemcost, quantity, discount, totalcost, finalcost;

    System.out.print("Item Number: ");
    item = keyboard.nextInt();

    final int LONGSWORD = 120;
    final int SHORTSWORD = 90;
    final int WARHAMMER = 80;
    final int RING = 150;
    final int POTION = 10;

    itemcost = 0;

    if (item == 1)
    {
        itemcost = LONGSWORD;
    }

    if (item == 2)
    {
        itemcost = SHORTSWORD;
    }   

    if (item == 3)
    {
        itemcost = WARHAMMER;
    }   

    if (item == 4)
    {
        itemcost = RING;
    }

    if (item == 5)
    {
        itemcost = POTION;
    }

    System.out.print("Quantity of Item: ");
    quantity = keyboard.nextInt();  

    totalcost = itemcost * quantity;

    System.out.println("Total Cost: " + totalcost);

    if (quantity >= 3)
    {
        discount = totalcost * (1/10);
    }

    else
    {
        discount = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("Discount: " + discount);
```

Comment: at which line you get the error, please mention it

Answer (score 8):

You are experiencing the oh-so-common *integer division* issue.

```
discount = totalcost * (1/10);
```

`1/10` is 0, so `discount` will be 0.  Use this instead:

```
discount = (int) (totalcost * (0.1));
```

Comment: Once I change the code to discount = totalcost * (0.1); I receive the error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int, how can I fix that?

Comment: Oops, you would need to cast back to `int` as well.

Comment: @katef:- You need to try this: `discount = (int) (totalcost * (0.1));`

Comment: @katef:- Try this: `discount = (int) (totalcost * (0.1));` You are missing the left paranthesis.

Answer (score 3):

You need to try

```
discount = totalcost * (0.1);
```

instead of

```
discount = totalcost * (1/10);
```

As 1/10 will result in 0(integer division) or else change it like

```
discount = totalcost * (1/10.0);
```

Also I would suggest you to change the type of `discount` to `double` instead of `int` else you need to cast it like this:

```
discount = (int) (totalcost * (0.1));
```

The reason why I am saying to change the type to double is because the discount could be in `decimals` also so it would be better to store it in `double` instead casting it to `int`.

Comment: The OP specifically states he wants "any decimals should be truncated"

Comment: @pathfinderelite:- Yes I am aware of that. I just made a point at the last stating my reasoning.